# Working with the elements of the "matrix" created by genfromtxt, Python3.4

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, genfromtxt

I import a .txt file with the command `tab = np.genfromtxt()` and it creates a kind of matrix. I need to work with its contents. 
When I visualize the elements with the command

```
for i in range n:
    print(tab[n][:])
```

it works and I can use matrix elements with `[][]` like if the first is the line number and the second the column one.
Instead when I use the command `tab[0][:]` the command is like I used `tab[:][0]`, i.e. I can visualize only the line 0 with all its elements (`tab[0][:]=tab[:][0]`).
What's the way I can move in a fixed column number and use all the line elements without a cicle "for i in range()" type?
Thank you.

Comment: Show us `tab.shape` and `tab.dtype`.

Comment: [See the docs here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All indices of a numpy array should be in a single `[]` separated by commas (ie `tab[i,j]`), if you provide just one index you get an array with the first dimension equal to that index (a row in this case). So `tab[:]` returns the whole matrix again. When you apply `[0]` over `tab[:]` it's the same as `tab[0]`

For iterating over columns:

```
for i in range n:
    print(tab[:,n])
```

For iterating over rows:

```
for i in range n:
    print(tab[n,:])
```